# Angular 7 npm run serve:ssr fails while using it after installing angular universal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, webpack, angular-universal

`npm run serve:ssr

> dealer-sites-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr C:\Users\ehsaan\Desktop\checkNow\DealerSites.App
>   node local.js

Listening on: http://localhost:4000
ERROR TypeError: **$.ajax is not a function**
    at ConfigService.module.exports../src/app/_configurationservice/config.service.ts.ConfigService.run (C:\Users\ehsaan\Desktop\checkNow\DealerSites.App\dist\server.js:132942:11)
`

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "dealer-sites-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node local.js",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run DealerSitesApp:server:production",
    "server": "node local.js",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:ssr",
    "serve:prerender": "node static.js",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build:prod && node dist/prerender.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.2",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/common": "0.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "0.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.11.4",
    "angular-colorbox": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "domino": "^2.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-colorbox": "^1.6.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^7.9.10",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.54",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}


`

**Here is my angular.json**

{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "DealerSitesApp": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {},
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/DealerSitesApp",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                            "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js",
                            "node_modules/jquery-colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"
                        ],
                        "es5BrowserSupport": true
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "DealerSitesApp:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "DealerSitesApp:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "DealerSitesApp:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "DealerSitesApp-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "DealerSitesApp:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "DealerSitesApp:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "DealerSitesApp"
}

**This is my app.module**

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
import { NgxCurrencyModule } from 'ngx-currency';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { InventoryComponent } from './vehicles/vehicle-inventory/inventory.component';
import { FinancingComponent, SafePipe } from './financing/financing.component';
import { LocationComponent } from './location/location.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { VehicleDetailComponent } from './vehicles/vehicle-detail/vehicle-detail.component';
import { EmailDetailsComponent } from './vehicles/email-details/email-details.component';
import { RequestInfoComponent } from './vehicles/request-info/request-info.component';
import { ColorboxComponent } from './vehicles/colorbox/colorbox.component';



import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { AppConstants } from './_models/constants';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './_services/token.interceptor';

import { AppInitializer } from './_configurationservice/app-initializer';
import { ConfigService } from './_configurationservice/config.service';

import { VehicleService } from './_services/vehicle.service';
import { StartupService } from './_services/startup.service';
import { SiteService } from './_services/site.service';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';

import { VehicleDetailResolver } from './_resolver/vehicle-detail.resolver';
import { InventoryListResolver } from './_resolver/inventory-list.resolver';



export function initialize_app(appInitializer: AppInitializer) {
  return () => appInitializer.run();
}
export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
export function startupServiceFactory(startupservice: StartupService): Function {
  return () => startupservice.load();
}

export let options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>);

// export let customCurrencyMaskConfig = {
//   align: 'left',
//   allowNegative: false,
//   allowZero: true,
//   decimal: ',',
//   precision: 3,
//   prefix: '$',
//   suffix: '',
//   thousands: '.',
//   nullable: true
// };

export let customCurrencyMaskConfig = {
  align: 'left',
  allowNegative: false,
  allowZero: true,
  decimal: ',',
  precision: 0,
  prefix: '$',
  suffix: '',
  thousands: ',',
  nullable: true
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SafePipe,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    InventoryComponent,
    FinancingComponent,
    LocationComponent,
    VehicleDetailComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    EmailDetailsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavComponent,
    ColorboxComponent,
    RequestInfoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    NgxCurrencyModule.forRoot(customCurrencyMaskConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
  //   JwtModule.forRoot({
  //     config:{
  //        tokenGetter:tokenGetter,
  //        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:44346'],
  //        blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:44346/api/auth']
  //     }
  //  })
  ],
  providers: [
    InventoryListResolver,
    VehicleDetailResolver,
    SiteService,
    AuthService,
    VehicleService,
    AppInitializer,
    AppConstants,
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useClass: ConfigService,
      deps: [AppConstants]
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initialize_app,
      deps: [AppInitializer],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use jQuery with angular universal. You should use the standard `HttpClient` to make an ajax call to your backend or whatever in your `ConfigService`

As a general rule, it is not recommended to use jQuery with angular